# How to override style in Angular8 .pug file?

Tags: css, sass, styles, pug, angular8

I created 'modal component'.
This modal invokes to 'another component' in .pug file.
So technically I'm using style and content for 'modal component' from 'another component'.

But I want to override styles in my 'modal component'.

How can I do it? It takes by default styles from 'another component'.

I can't just change styles in 'another component' because it is used in few places in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of CSS specificity  if I've understood you correctly.

If you were to add a class to a parent element in your modal component that is invoking the other component you could take advantage of the specificity

.modal { blah }  // this would be the invoked components styles

.my-modal .modal { overwriting styles }  // this would be in your modal styles

Alternatively if you were to use ngClass on the parent container invoking the modal you'd be adding some inline style to the parent which would also take precedence over css from a stylesheet